# Angularjs Factory deferred's data disapearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, deferred

I'm trying to do a caching factory for http requests, so it doesn't make the server do a lot of work for the same request. But It seems my way of using deferred "swallows" the data, and I don't know why.

Console output for below:

*data fetched:

Object {state: "OK", data: Object, errorMessage: null, exception: null}

success

undefined*

**ImportFactory:**

```
factory("importFactory", function ($http, $q, loggingService) {
return{
    fetchedData: [],
    cacheTransport: function (transportsId, data) {
        this.fetchedData.push({"transportsId": transportsId, "data": data});
    },
    getImport: function (transportsId) {
        var factory = this;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var preFetchedTransport = this.findTransport(transportsId);
        if (preFetchedTransport === null) {
            console.log('fetching from backend');
            return $http.post("/import/create/" + transportsId).then(function (data) {
                console.log('data fetched:');
                console.log(data);
                factory.cacheTransport(transportsId, data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
        }
        preFetchedTransport = deferred.promise;
        return preFetchedTransport;
    },
    findTransport: function (transportsId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.fetchedData.length; i++) {
            var transportObj = this.fetchedData[i];
            if (transportObj.transportsId === transportsId) {
                return transportObj.data;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

});

**Controller**

```
.controller('ImportController', function ($scope, $routeParams, importFactory){
    $scope.transportId = $routeParams.id;
    importFactory.getImport($scope.transportId).then(function (successData) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(successData);
    }, function (errorData) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(errorData);
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the built in cache of $http, like $http.post(url, { cache: true})

Comment: Because I need to update this cache as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need this: [**Demo here.**](http://jsbin.com/notawo/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
var cachedPromises = {};
return {
  getStuff: function(id) {
    if (!cachedPromises[id]) {
      cachedPromises[id] = $http.post("/import/create/" + id).then(function(resp) {
        return resp.data;
      });
    }
    return cachedPromises[id];
  }
};
```

Now, when you fetch that data, you can manipulate and it will be changed when you access it in the future.

```
myService.getStuff(whatever).then(function(data) {
  data.foo = 'abc';
});

//elsewhere
myService.getStuff(whatever).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.foo); // 'abc'
});
```

Here's a demo that does this, as well as a view updating trick (bind the object to the view before the data comes in), and an idea of how you could change the data separately from the cache, in case you want to have the original data and the changing data. http://jsbin.com/notawo/2/edit

Remember to avoid that nasty promise anti-pattern. If you already have a promise, use that instead of creating another with `$q`. `$http` already returns a promise and that promise is sufficient for whatever you need if you use it properly.

Comment: Again thanks a lot for showing me who to really use promises :)

Answer (score 0):

just change the loop condition look like this and then test i think your function and defer is work fine but the loop does not sent the correct data

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.fetchedData.length; i++) {
        if (this.fetchedData[i].transportsId === transportsId) {
            return this.fetchedData[i].data;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting undefined is you are not returning anything from the $http.post().then() !

Also in your getImport() function you are returning an empty promise when the transport is already cached. You need to resolve it to your already cached transport object.

```
getImport: function (transportsId) {
    var factory = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var preFetchedTransport = this.findTransport(transportsId);
    if (preFetchedTransport === null) {
        console.log('fetching from backend');
        return $http.post("/import/create/" + transportsId).then(function (data) {
            console.log('data fetched:');
            console.log(data);
            factory.cacheTransport(transportsId, data);
            return data;                //this was missing
        });
    }

    // resolve it with transport object if cached
    deferred.resolve(preFetchedTransport); 
    return deferred.promise;
},
```